# Unknown column in having clause

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have trouble with following
[laravel query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULw0K.png)

Laravel[5.7] throws error

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'team_ref_bonus_sum' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` inner join `users__affiliate__structures` as `aff` on `users`.`id` = `aff`.`user_id` left join `users` as `upline` on `users`.`upline_id` = `upline`.`id` group by `users`.`id` having team_ref_bonus_sum IS NOT NULL)"
```

[Same query in sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v424y.png)

SQL query works well

P.S sorry for using image's but stackoverflow force me to add more information because my post is mostly code...

Comment: Are you trying to paginate a query with a group-by ?

Comment: @apokryfos yes, is this problem? Oh, i find out this in documentation. shit...

Comment: Yes, to paginate Laravel needs to find out how many total results there are and does this by replacing all selects with a `COUNT(*)` obviously this will break any custom columns you're selecting. It may be necessary to change to `simplePaginate` or manually use a `LengthAwarePaginator` and calculate the total expected results using another query tailored to the first one

Comment: @apokryfos thanks a lot